# How to generate function name using c macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

Macro "VER" is defined as "((u_long)1)" in some other header file which I can't change.

In my code I need to compose function "test_1" using "test" and the VER.
However compiler reported error since it was the "test_((u_long)1)" instead of  "test_1" generated.

My question is: **How to write macro so that it can generate "test_1"?**

Thanks in advance!

```
#define VER ((u_long)1)      /* This is defined in some other header file which I can't change*/

#define paste(x, y, z) x ## y ## z
#define paste2(x, y, z) paste(x, y, z)
#define fcall(fname) paste2(fname, _, VER)

int test_1() {
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  fcall( test )();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't guarantee it's 100% portable, but it should work:

```
#define VER ((u_long)1)

#define STRIP1(x) STRIP2 x

#define STRIP2(x) STRIP3 x

#define STRIP3(x)

#define paste(x, y, z) x ## y ## z
#define paste2(x, y, z) paste(x, y, z)
#define fcall(fname) paste2(fname, _, STRIP1(VER))
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/u1qR23)

It works by interpreting the parentheses inside the definition of `VER` as macro invocation. Here's the individual expansions, as they occur:

```
STRIP1(VER) // STRIP1 with argument VER

STRIP2 ((u_long)1) // STRIP2 with argument (u_long)1

STRIP3 (u_long)1  // STRIP3 with argument u_long, followed by 1

1
```

If we re-arrange the whitespace (it's insignificant anyway), we get this:

```
STRIP1(VER)

STRIP2((u_long) 1)

STRIP3(u_long) 1

1
```

Comment: That is very cool.  But if someone changes the definition of VER (say to (1)), it breaks.

Comment: @brianbeuning Of course. But then again, normally during development you are aware when "external code I can't modify" changes (e.g. because you've upgraded to a new version), so you can adapt the `STRIP` macros accordingly.

Comment: @hhwangcocora You might want to mark the answer as accepted, then (using the green tick-mark next to it). That's how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

With that source, you probably can't, since macro expansion is textual, so the `((u_long)1)` can not possibly become `1`.

One solution would of course be to actually write some code to print the actual value of `VER`. The other alternative is to convince the people that own the file you can't change that they should change it for you...

Answer (score 0):

As modified Angew version

```
#define VER ((u_long)1)

#define _(x) x
#define id(x) _(x)

#define STRIP3(x)
#define STRIP2(x) id(STRIP3 x)
#define STRIP1(x) id(STRIP2 x)

#define paste(x, y, z) x ## y ## z
#define paste2(x, y, z) paste(x, y, z)
#define fcall(fname) paste2(fname, _, STRIP1(VER))
```